# A question regarding the asymptotic behaviour of two functions

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Say we had a function, $f(x)$. And we proved that:
$$f(x)^2\sim 2f(x)$$
Now, this may be a stupid question, but does this mean the following?
$$f(x)\sim 2$$

Comment: No, it means $f(x)^2 - 2f(x)$ is infinitesimal in the limit of interest.

Comment: Depends on what $f\sim g$ means specifically. If it means that [$\lim\frac fg=1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis), then yes, since $$f(x)^2\sim2f(x)\iff\lim\frac{f(x)^2}{2f(x)}=1\iff\lim\frac{f(x)}2=1\iff f(x)\sim2$$

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Did you mean something like this? $$f(x)\sim\sqrt{2f(x)}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2..}}}}=2^{\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+..\right)}=2$$. So $f(x)\sim2$?